# Caffe: Check failed: Network should have exactly one output

Tags: android, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'm using the [Caffe android lib](https://github.com/sh1r0/caffe-android-lib) (based on the C++ api). I'm trying it with a GoogleNet model.
Unfortunatly it's giving me this error:

> ```
> Check failed: net_->num_outputs() == 1 Network should have exactly one output
> ```

I'm having the feeling I'm missing something stupid. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What implementation of GoogLeNet are you using?
Depending on the implementation, you might indeed get more than a single output.
The original GoogLeNet (published in CVPR 2015) had three "output" losses for training, so you might be using a similat prototxt resulting with several output layers.

Considering [this `deploy.prototxt`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_googlenet/deploy.prototxt) - it has only one output `"prob"`. However, the corresponding [`train_val.prototxt`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_googlenet/train_val.prototxt) has three outputs: `"loss1/loss1"`, `"loss2/loss1"` and `"loss3/loss3"`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I indeed switched back to that deploy but it's still giving me that error. Wierd part that the network used in the example for that library: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt is not

Comment: @Mozie you should check your `deploy.prototxt` - it might have more than a single output, it's not uncommon.

Comment: Thanks Shai, the last layer was indeed giving multiple ones, thanks! (Knew I was beeing stupid somewhere)

Comment: @Mozie running caffe on android makes you very "un-stupid", so you don't need to worry ;)

Comment: @Mozie Having same pb. Did you changed this one ? layer {
  name: "prob"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "loss3/classifier"
  top: "prob"
}